# SDWebImage in TableView Scroll Up

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` in my `swift 3.0.1` project with `xcode 8.1`.
I am able to get the image downloaded from a remote url and show in the image view of dynamic `cell` of the `tableview`.

The problem occurs when I scroll up in the `tableview`, the images get shrink.

Comment: Can you please share your code? Piece of code will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and its working for me.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cellId:String = "cellid"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! customcell
            let strUrlProfilepic = your image url path

        self.yourImageView.af_setImage(withURL: strUrlProfilepic, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage.jpeg"))
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: I used the above code.. self.yourImageView.af_setImage(withURL: strUrlProfilepic, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage.jpeg")). It's working now.

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then accept my answer.Thank you